# Given a file how to generate an NFA that accepts only those words present in the file?

Tags: computer-science, theory, finite-automata, formal-languages, automata-theory

Given any document, I want to be able to generate an NFA that accepts only those words present in the document.
Basically, I want to write a function that is able to dynamically generate NFA's from any document.
Are there any pre-existing algorithms that already do that?

Comment: Despite the name, most regex engine now is actually an NFA. For example in Python you can use `\b(word1|word2|word3)\b` to match a list of words.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is an NFA with no requirements the construction is almost trivial.

For each word w, create a distinct branch in your NFA with |w| + 1 states (not including the initial state). From the start state, add an empty transition to the first state and then add a transition from the nth state to the n+1th state on the nth character of w. Make the |w|+1th state accepting.

This will give you a DFA with as many states as you have symbols + words in your file. If you want fewer states, you could do something more layered by creating a first "layer" for all first letters in all words, a second "layer" for all second letters in all words, etc., and add transitions from states in layer n to states in layer n+1 if there are words w that make the transitions valid. Indeed, if you do this right you'll end up with a DFA and it will likely be minimal as well (exercise: prove or disprove this).